text overruns width of paragraph
I'm having a very strange issue and one which I've never seen in more than 20 years of web development. I have text which is overrunning the width of the paragraph which contains it:

My client has requested the Duffy Script font from Adobe which might be the problem, since when I switch to sans serif, the issue goes away. But I'd really like to fix it if I can!
I've created a simple jsfiddle which shows the problem - you can simply resize the right-hand pane to see the problem I screen-capped in the image: https://jsfiddle.net/GeorgeMooWoof/4x50etdy/6/
Can anyone help at all please?
Thanks so much


@import url("https://use.typekit.net/twt4ckp.css");
.container {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

p {
  font-family: "duffy-script", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
<div class="container">
  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>




@Nexo I'm able to replicate the issue on Edge(126.0.2592.68) and the latest Chrome.

@Nexo I didn't even check, but now I have! It's happening in Safari, Chrome and Brave but it's fine in FF.

The issue occurs because of the font. I tested your code with multiple fonts.

Thanks @JaydenJiang, but I already knew that. I've done that too. I was hoping someone might know of a workaround. Strange that Firefox renders it okay if it's ONLY the font, don't you think?

I think I may have found a warkaround. Adding
letter-spacing: 0.01px;
to the CSS appears to fix it. I'm doing some more tests...

See @herrstrietzel's post for details and explanation. As mentioned inside, you can use font-variant-ligatures:no-contextual (as pre spec preferred over font-feature-setting) to disable display of contextual alternates.
(Setting optimizeSpeed as below works because of its side-effect of disabling ligatures. Same with adding a positive letter-spacing.)

Setting text-rendering:optimizeSpeed fixes the problem for me (on Chrome and Edge).


@import url("https://use.typekit.net/twt4ckp.css");
.container {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: yellow;
}

.par {
  font-family: "duffy-script", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  text-rendering: optimizeSpeed;
}
<div class="container">
  <p class="par">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor
    in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
</div>



As commented by the OP, adding letter-spacing: 0.01px appears to fix the problem as well.


@import url("https://use.typekit.net/twt4ckp.css");
.container {
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* background: yellow; */
}

.par {
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: "duffy-script", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 233px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
  letter-spacing: 0.01px;
}
<div class="container">
        <p class="par">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        </p>
    </div>




Thanks @SyndRain, taking time to help is much appreciated. Can you explain why font-variant-ligatures: no-contextual is preferred over herrstrietzel's suggestion of using font-feature-settings:  'calt' 0 ?

@GeorgePorge Might not matter in your case but as mentioned in the link its preferred because font-feature-settings are lower lever interfaces that should be avoided when there is higher level option being provided for the sake of cascading and compatibility.

@SyndRain: sorry, my previous comment about comparing the contextual alternate feature to ligatures was plain nonsense! (the W3C draft oviously made the same mistake – they've often make questionable semantic choices). I've updated my answer with some additional info. GeorgePorge: since it's a bug I don't think we can depict a solution to be the ideal workaround. However, SyndRain's answer deserves to be tagged as the accepted answer. Ideally we all keep an eye on this subject and share our findings once there is any progress to report (... it may take some time ;)

I do think accepting @herrstrietzel's answer makes way more sense for future reader.  My answer don't give any explanation. It just provided a workaround when I had no clue why it worked. Interesting reading!

@SyndRain, herrstritzel thanks both for taking so much time to investigate and help. It's massively appreciated. Take the rest of the day off, both of you, and have a beer. Tell your boss I said you could :o)

This chromium/blink based bug is caused by the calt contextual alternate Opentype feature.
Apparently, chromium/blink based (Chrome, Brave, Opera, Vivaldi  ... and Internet Expl... Edge) as well as webkit (safari, web/epiphany, midori) browsers can't calculate the current word length correctly for appropriate line breaks with this feature enabled.
So it's definitely a bug (Firefox has no problems with it).
See also @SyndRain's answer providing other workarounds.
font-feature-settings:  'calt' 0;

Does fix the problem while enabling other features (e.g ligatures)


@import url("https://use.typekit.net/twt4ckp.css");

.container {
  padding-right: 20px;
  background: yellow;
  resize:both;
  overflow:auto;
  line-height:1.5em;
  max-width:100%;
  
}
p {
  font-family: "duffy-script", sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.no-feat{
   font-feature-settings:  'calt' 0;
}
  <h3>Resize me</h3>

<div class="container">
  <p class="feat">
  firm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  
    <p class="no-feat">
  firm Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
  </p>
  
</div>



Contextual alternate vs. ligature feature
At first glance both features serve a similar purpose – a certain sequence of characters is replaced by another visual representation A.K.A "glyph".

ligatures: replace/substitute a sequence of characters by a single glyph replacement.
For instance "ffi" (3 characters - 3 glyphs) get replaced by a single compound glyph "ffi" – translated to SVG graphic lingo: three separate paths are replaced by a single compound path. Worth mentioning: in Browsers all ligatures are instantly decomposed into the separate glyphs once we apply a custom letter spacing. Just because we can't automatically adjust inner glyph geometry as introduced by a ligature glyph (we would need some extra logic to interpolate the "ffi" path data to respond to this change to get the stems between "f-f-i" narrower )
contextual substitutions: based on the character input sequence, glyphs can be substituted ... well contextually. The main difference: we're substituting a sequence of characters by multiple glyphs. For instance we can replace subsequent occurences of the letter "e" like in "Queen" according to a replacement rule that replaces only the 2nd occurrence of "e" with an alternate glyph. In other words we don't have a "fixed" "ee" ligature but alternate glyphs for "e". Maybe even 3 or more alternates.

Fun facts: OK, it's a bug!
While I can confirm the the aforementioned workarounds work such as custom letter spacing – some of them shouldn't;)
At least not if the opentype feature definitions were perfectly implemented.

custom letter-spacing disables all ligatures – which can be a bummer for quite a few right-to-left based languages using ligatures like e.g Arabic or Farsi (especially when mixed with latin text) – but it actually shouldn't make a difference since we're replacing separate character inputs with separate glyph representations.
The current W3C draft for higher-level opentype feature controls is questionable font-variant-ligatures: contextual – it's definitely not a ligature feature

Further reading
From Microsoft's Opentype documentation

Lookup type 4 subtable: ligature substitution
Lookup type 5 subtable: contextual substitution
Lookup type 6 subtable: chained contexts substitutio

Summary for designers from typenetwork.com

OpenType at Work | Contextual Alternates


Ah genius, wonder  if this problem persists in Chromium when other fonts have Contextual alternates being set.

Thanks @herrstrietzel, that's incredibly useful. I've never heard of this before and I've even created my own fonts in the past!

@GeorgePorge: Frankly I think this quite advanced open type feature is rather the domain of comic/graphic-novel lettering use cases - to avoid an obviously artificial appearance when displaying two identical  letters in a sequence. For web font usage you usually try to keep the font complexity and file size as low as possible.  So I think it's rather rare you'll ever experience any conflicts with other web fonts - just because there are not so many fonts deploying this feature. Unless you're mixing multiple "handwritten" fonts with contextual alternates ...
